# Send video synchronously to AppSink

Tags: java, gstreamer, java-gstreamer

I'm using gstreamer-java to send data via UDP through a custom AppSink. Here's how it's effectively setup:

`fileSrc ! streamTee ! displayQueue ! tsdemux ! demuxQueue ! (mpeg2dec || h264dec) ! videosink`

and

`streamTee ! sendQueue ! udpSink`

I would like to send the data in a way that simulates a live stream. I am assuming that the only way to do this is to synchronize the sending with the playback through the videoSink. That is, send at 1.0x playback speed.

However, Setting the udpSink's `sync` property doesn't seem to change anything. I have verified that packets get sent out as fast as possible because of the sendQueue.

Do I need to add the streamTee between other elements? Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Moving the streamTee to after the displayQueue seems to have solved this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the streamTee to after the displayQueue seems to have solved this problem. The sync property doesn't seem to do anything.

The UDP packets seem to be sent out a tad ahead of the videoSink's displayed video, but it's consistently .5-1.0s ahead at the end of any video of any length. So it seems like it's sync'd enough.